# How to convert Google Input typed number String into integer as Store into MySql DB?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-2.0

I want to store google input typed number into database whose column is Integer. when i want to convert it to integer it gives me error said that Input string was not in correct formate how to solve this Problem?

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=syits03-pc;Database=Demo;Uid=root;Pwd=kbabu4668;CharSet=utf8;");
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into tblnew(str,num,numstr) values(@str,@num,@numstr)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", textBox1.Text);
MySqlCommand cmd1= new MySqlCommand("Select str from tblnew where id=1",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numstr", textBox3.Text);
object obj= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if (obj != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
}
```

Comment: presumably it is the `Convert.ToInt32` that throws; so: what is `cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString()`, and what culture is your machine running in? (in case this is a culture formatting issue). Does it not work if you just do `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", cmd1.ExecuteScalar());` ?

Comment: @Marc Gravell Then How to Solve this Culture Formating Issue

Comment: simple: don't treat numbers as strings; or if you must: pass the correct culture to the format/parse methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
`using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = syits03 - pc; Database = Demo; Uid = root; Pwd = kbabu4668; CharSet = utf8; "))
{
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select top 1 str from tblnew where id -1", con);
string num = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
string cmdText = string.Concat("insert into tblnew(str, num, numstr) values(", textBox1.Text, ",", num, ",", textBox3.Text, ")");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}`
Some possible issues you should think of are:

- What if nothing is returned from cmd1 and so a blank value is passed to @num?
- cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is not meant to return anything, so assigning it to an object may not be the best idea. Instead you could put it in a try/catch. e.g. `try 
  {
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  MessageBox.Show("Stored Proc failed with error: " + ex.ToString());
  }`

Answer (score 0):

looks like your cmd.executescalar might be returning null sometimes which is converted to "" by tostring() function this may be the reason error is coming if you are not sure about if input coming will be correct or not you can always try using int.TryParse() please read about the function before using